# custom mutex - all goroutines are asleep - deadlock

Tags: go, parallel-processing, runtime, deadlock, goroutine

Im trying to make a simple mutext with a specific behavior. But the specific behavior is imposible because golang doesnt work out of the blue

simple test code returns an error:
all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

A first block with `for` works perfectly without an error
Second block failures on m.Unlock()

What's wrong? What's happened? I am only human. I write code like human. And there is human logic:

1. I opened the channel with buffer
2. I sent the value to the channel
   What go-routines should I think about?

```
Result:
=== RUN   TestNiceMutex_Lock
=== RUN   TestNiceMutex_Lock/test
   nicemutex_test.go:36: main: lock
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
testing.(*T).Run(0xc00007b380, {0xcee048?, 0xc1f6cd?}, 0xcf8388)
C:/Program Files/Go/src/testing/testing.go:1649 +0x3c8
testing.runTests.func1(0xdecd00?)
C:/Program Files/Go/src/testing/testing.go:2054 +0x3e
testing.tRunner(0xc00007b380, 0xc0000b7c48)
C:/Program Files/Go/src/testing/testing.go:1595 +0xff
testing.runTests(0xc00009a140?, {0xde0d90, 0x1, 0x1}, {0xbc3345?, 0xc0000b7d08?, 0x0?})
C:/Program Files/Go/src/testing/testing.go:2052 +0x445
testing.(*M).Run(0xc00009a140)
C:/Program Files/Go/src/testing/testing.go:1925 +0x636
main.main()
_testmain.go:47 +0x19c

goroutine 6 [chan receive]:
testing.(*T).Run(0xc00007b520, {0xceae57?, 0xc78420?}, 0xc00023c000)
C:/Program Files/Go/src/testing/testing.go:1649 +0x3c8
simply/nicemutex.TestNiceMutex_Lock(0x0?)
C:/Users/Aleksey/go/src/simply/nicemutex/nicemutex_test.go:26 +0xba
testing.tRunner(0xc00007b520, 0xcf8388)
C:/Program Files/Go/src/testing/testing.go:1595 +0xff
created by testing.(*T).Run in goroutine 1
C:/Program Files/Go/src/testing/testing.go:1648 +0x3ad

(content is repeated)

goroutine 97 [chan send]:
simply/nicemutex.lock()
C:/Users/Aleksey/go/src/simply/nicemutex/nicemutex.go:6
simply/nicemutex.TestNiceMutex_Lock.func1()
C:/Users/Aleksey/go/src/simply/nicemutex/nicemutex_test.go:12 +0x25
created by simply/nicemutex.TestNiceMutex_Lock in goroutine 6
C:/Users/Aleksey/go/src/simply/nicemutex/nicemutex_test.go:11 +0x2c


goroutine 117 [chan send]:
simply/nicemutex.(*NiceMutex).Lock(0xc000250008)
C:/Users/Aleksey/go/src/simply/nicemutex/nicemutex.go:25 +0x99
simply/nicemutex.TestNiceMutex_Lock.func2.1()
C:/Users/Aleksey/go/src/simply/nicemutex/nicemutex_test.go:32 +0x5f
created by simply/nicemutex.TestNiceMutex_Lock.func2 in goroutine 116
C:/Users/Aleksey/go/src/simply/nicemutex/nicemutex_test.go:30 +0xa5


Process finished with the exit code 1



package nicemutex

import (
    "sync"
    "testing"
    "time"
)

func TestNiceMutex_Lock(t *testing.T) {
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        go func() {
            lock()
            unlock()
        }()
        lock()
        unlock()
    }

    tests := []struct {
        name string
    }{
        {"test"},
    }
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            var m NiceMutex
            m.Lock()
            wg.Add(1)
            go func() {
                defer m.Unlock()
                m.Lock()
                t.Log("go: lock")
                wg.Done()
            }()
            t.Log("main: lock")
            time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
            m.Unlock() // <- error
            wg.Wait()
        })
    }
}

package nicemutex

var internalLock = make(chan struct{}, 1)

func lock() {
    internalLock <- struct{}{} // <- error
}

func unlock() {
    <-internalLock
}

type NiceMutex struct {
    ch chan struct{}
}

func (m *NiceMutex) Lock() {
    defer unlock()
    lock()

    if m.ch == nil {
        m.ch = make(chan struct{}, 1)
    }
    m.ch <- struct{}{}
}

func (m *NiceMutex) Unlock() {
    defer unlock()
    lock() // <- error

    if m.ch == nil {
        return
    }
    <-m.ch
}
```

Updated:
New version - same result

```
package nicemutex

import (
    "log"
    "time"
)

var (
    internalLock2 = make(chan struct{}, 1)
    TraceEnabled2 = false
)

type NiceMutex2 struct {
    ch       chan struct{}
    lockedOn int64
}

func (m *NiceMutex2) Lock() {
    internalLock2 <- struct{}{}
    defer func() { <-internalLock2 }()

    m.lockedOn = time.Now().UnixNano()

    if m.ch == nil {
        m.ch = make(chan struct{}, 1)
    }
    m.ch <- struct{}{}

    trace2("locked")
}

func (m *NiceMutex2) LockForSec() {
    internalLock2 <- struct{}{}
    defer func() { <-internalLock2 }()

    on := time.Now().UnixNano()
    m.lockedOn = on

    if m.ch == nil {
        m.ch = make(chan struct{}, 1)
    }
    m.ch <- struct{}{}

    go func(lockedOn int64) {
        <-time.After(time.Second)

        internalLock2 <- struct{}{}
        defer func() { <-internalLock2 }()

        if m.lockedOn == lockedOn {
            select {
            case <-m.ch:
                trace2("timeout used", true)
            default:
                trace2("timeout ignore")
            }
        }
    }(on)

    trace2("locked")
}

func (m *NiceMutex2) Unlock() {
    internalLock2 <- struct{}{}
    defer func() { <-internalLock2 }()

    m.lockedOn = time.Now().UnixNano()

    if m.ch == nil {
        return
    }
    select {
    case <-m.ch:
    default:
    }

    trace2("unlocked")
}

func trace2(msg string, ignoreEnabling ...bool) {
    if TraceEnabled2 || (len(ignoreEnabling) > 0 && ignoreEnabling[0]) {
        log.Println(msg)
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the simple and specific behavior you are looking for? What is this supposed to do that an already simple mutex cannot? You made `Unlock` block on the same semaphore that blocks `Lock`, so if there is anything waiting for `Lock`, it will prevent any `Unlock` from completing, hence deadlocking the whole thing.

Comment: Same problem with sync.mutex

Comment: Same problem with sync.mutex. Im looking for a func with locking timeout. Because an enterprise system in a production version must work without deadlock and even locks. Because locking is process to solve a joined memory access, but I think there is a big thouble in golang. This behavior of channels and mutex is unsupported way to use it in production version. May be not. But where is a proof?

Comment: There is no trouble, Go works in countless production systems, under high levels of concurrency. It’s not clear what you’re asking for here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

Firstly, using channels like this as a mutex isn't exactly "simple". Reasoning about concurrency state is complex.

The reason for the deadlock is because the channel buffers are full.

- main `m.Lock()` fills `internalLock`
- main `m.Lock()` fills `m.ch`
- main `m.Lock()` drains `internalLock`
- goroutine `m.Lock()` fills `internalLock`
- goroutine `m.Lock()` blocks as `m.ch` buffer is full
- goroutine `m.Lock()` **never drains `internalLock`**
- main `m.Unlock()` blocks as `internalLock` buffer is full
- main `m.Unlock()` **never drains `m.ch`**

Both the goroutine and main paths are blocked forever. The goroutine will never drain `internalLock` until it can write to `m.ch`. And the opposite is true for main.

Comment: I disagree. There is "defer unlock()" in NiceMitex.Lock and this instruction is to drain it

Comment: @AlekseyFomin: My apologies — I read the program's intent incorrectly. I've updated the answer and tested it locally.

Comment: I made new version without a func calls. Look. Same result. I don't think that one-buffered channel can't write and read in the same place of code

Comment: What do you mean by not being able to be read and written from? The updated version has the same problem because it's still relying on one channel draining to drain another.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake! :) coxley, you are right
I wrote locking only on start (if chan is nil) and it is working perfect

```
package nicemutex

import (
    "log"
    "time"
)

var (
    internalLock2 = make(chan struct{}, 1)
    TraceEnabled2 = false
)

type NiceMutex2 struct {
    ch       chan struct{}
    lockedOn int64
}

func (m *NiceMutex2) Lock() {
    if m.ch == nil {
        func() {
            internalLock2 <- struct{}{}
            defer func() { <-internalLock2 }()
            m.ch = make(chan struct{}, 1)
        }()
    }
    m.ch <- struct{}{}

    trace2("locked")
}

func (m *NiceMutex2) LockForSec() {
    if m.ch == nil {
        func() {
            internalLock2 <- struct{}{}
            defer func() { <-internalLock2 }()
            m.ch = make(chan struct{}, 1)
        }()
    }
    m.ch <- struct{}{}

    go func() {
        <-time.After(time.Second)

        select {
        case <-m.ch:
            trace2("timeout used", true)
        default:
            trace2("timeout ignore")
        }
    }()

    trace2("locked")
}

func (m *NiceMutex2) Unlock() {
    if m.ch == nil {
        return
    }
    select {
    case <-m.ch:
    default:
    }

    trace2("unlocked")
}

func trace2(msg string, ignoreEnabling ...bool) {
    if TraceEnabled2 || (len(ignoreEnabling) > 0 && ignoreEnabling[0]) {
        log.Println(msg)
    }
}
```